# C# Binary Array "{ 84, 01, 00, 00 }" changed to "54 01 00 00" in Windows Registry

Tags: c#, binary, registry

I'm using C# to write the following binary value to the system registry:

```
  byte[] valueToSet = { 84, 01, 00, 00 };
  Registry.SetValue(keyName, "00036601", valueToSet);
  // returns void as expected.
```

When I view the written value using regedit, I see the displayed value as 54 01 00 00.  This is incorrect

Conversely when I set the value to 84,01,00,00 manually in the registry, and run this code

```
object ttt = Registry.GetValue(keyName, "00036601", null);
// returns 132, 1, 0, 0
```

Is this an Endian issue?  What is the correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a hexadecimal issue. RegEdit displays values in hexadecimal, and you're working with decimal in C#.

The two values are equivalent:

```
0x54 == 84
```

Answer (score 7):

The registry editor displays the value in hexadecimal. The decimal value 84 is equal to the hexadecimal value 0x54, and hexadecimal 0x84 is equal to decimal 132.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to specify the literals in *hex*. However, without the `0x` hex-prefix, the compiler interprets them as *decimals*.

Try this instead:

```
byte[] valueToSet = { 0x84, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

Answer (score 2):

The values shown in the registry for binary types are in hexidecimal notation.  Decimal 84 == hex 0x54.

Answer (score 1):

interesting thing to note is that `84` (decimal) == `54` (hex)